# change order of pages of .tif documents using java

Tags: java, user-interface, drag-and-drop, tiff

is there any library to work with .tif files using java?
it is a desktop application and I need to

1. edit tiff document
2. change the order of pages
3. save new tiff document
4. do it using drag and drop

Comment: This question belongs to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The TIFF uses a linked "directory" (IFD) structure, so you should be able to change the order of the pages, just by changing a few offsets in the file. But as soon as you start editing variable length fields or the compressed image data, things get a bit more complicated... So, yes, use a library! 